# how to get google chrome web browser active tab's Url (vb6)

Tags: curl, vb6

i do not get the url from chrome Version29.because url control can not be found using spy++.

```
     Option Explicit

    Private Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
    Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = &HE

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

    Private Sub Command1_Click()
        Dim dhWnd As Long
        Dim chWnd As Long

        Dim Web_Caption As String * 256
        Dim Web_hWnd As Long

        Dim URL As String * 256
        Dim URL_hWnd As Long

        dhWnd = GetDesktopWindow
        chWnd = FindWindowEx(dhWnd, 0, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbNullString)
        Web_hWnd = FindWindowEx(dhWnd, chWnd, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbNullString)
        URL_hWnd = FindWindowEx(Web_hWnd, 0, "Chrome_OmniboxView", vbNullString)

        Call SendMessage(Web_hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, 256, ByVal Web_Caption)
        Call SendMessage(URL_hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, 256, ByVal URL)

        MsgBox Split(Web_Caption, Chr(0))(0) & vbCrLf & Split(URL, Chr(0))(0)

    End Sub
```

I am using vb6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is no longer using Chrome_OmniboxView.
I'm also looking for a new solution...

Answer (score 0):

This MASM32 code used to work on earlier versions of chrome:

```
**EnumChildChrome** PROC hwndChild:DWORD,lParam:DWORD     
      LOCAL       lpClassUrl[64]     :BYTE

      invoke      RtlZeroMemory,addr lpClassUrl, 64   
      invoke      GetClassName, hwndChild, addr lpClassUrl, 64  

      ; Get URL from AddressBar class Chrome_AutocompleteEditView.
      ; Get URL from AddressBar class Chrome_OmniboxView.    
      ; Get URL from AddressBar class Chrome_WidgetWin_1.  
      .IF (dword ptr [lpClassUrl+7]=='otuA') || (dword ptr [lpClassUrl+7]=='inmO') || (dword ptr [lpClassUrl+7]=='gdiW')               
         invoke   RtlZeroMemory,wText, BUFSIZE     
         invoke   SendMessage, hwndChild, WM_GETTEXT, BUFSIZE, wText  
         invoke   WriteToMem,3,addr startURL,wText,addr endURL
      .ENDIF

      mov         eax,hwndChild
      ret
EnumChildChrome ENDP
```

However, to capture URLs from the most recent versions of chrome, I've written this hacked version below. (Can easily be ported to C, VB etc.,...) It essentially uses the Chrome Tab Title (WinText) as a search key into the History file. Also, Chrome seems to delay URL writes, so that's an obstacle to overcome. Currently, I make several passes thru the history, for say 5 seconds, then abort if nothing found. :(

```
        ...
    googlePath        db  "%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History",0
    GoogleChrome      db  " - Google Chrome",0        
        ...
              invoke      HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, BUFSIZE
              mov         googleHistory,eax   
              invoke      HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, MAXSIZE
              mov         WinText,eax
              invoke      HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, BUFSIZE
              mov         winTitle,eax
              invoke      HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, BUFSIZE
              mov         wwinTitle,eax
              invoke      HeapAlloc, hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, BUFSIZE
              mov         uwinTitle,eax   
        ...
; --- Find Google History file path ---
      invoke      RtlZeroMemory,googleHistory,BUFSIZE   
      invoke      ExpandEnvironmentStrings, addr googlePath, googleHistory, BUFSIZE
...
        Chrome PROC  
        LOCAL found_url_ok    :DWORD

              mov         found_url_ok,FALSE
              invoke      readdiskfile,googleHistory,addr lpMem,addr lpLen
              .IF (eax==0)
                 ret
              .ENDIF

              invoke      RtlZeroMemory,winTitle, BUFSIZE
              invoke      RtlZeroMemory,wwinTitle, BUFSIZE
              invoke      RtlZeroMemory,uwinTitle, BUFSIZE            

              ;; Chrome History Titles are stored in UTF8 format. Example: Polítiques i principis -----> Pol,0C3h,0ADh,tiques i principis
              invoke      szRemove,WinText,winTitle,addr GoogleChrome    
              invoke      CharToUTF8,winTitle,wwinTitle,uwinTitle  
              invoke      lstrlen,uwinTitle
              invoke      BinSearch,0,lpMem,lpLen,uwinTitle,eax  

        ; --- Search backwards looking for a begin url marker 01h ...
              .IF (eax!=-1)
                   mov    ecx,eax
                   add    eax,lpMem
                   mov    byte ptr[eax],0 ; end of url

                find_url_start:       
                   cmp    byte ptr[eax-1],01h
                   je     start_url      
                   dec    eax  
                   loop   find_url_start
                   jecxz  no_url_found

                start_url: 
                   invoke WriteToMem,3,addr startURL,eax,addr endURL 
                   mov    found_url_ok,TRUE       

                no_url_found:

              .ENDIF

              invoke GlobalFree,lpMem  

              mov    eax,found_url_ok  

              ret      
        Chrome ENDP


        CharToUTF8 proc pAsciiString:DWORD,pWideOutbuf:DWORD,pUTF8Outbuf:DWORD
        invoke lstrlen,pAsciiString
        invoke MultiByteToWideChar,CP_ACP,0,pAsciiString,-1,pWideOutbuf,eax
        invoke WideCharToMultiByte,CP_UTF8,0,pWideOutbuf,-1,pUTF8Outbuf,BUFSIZE,NULL,NULL
        ret
        CharToUTF8 endp
```

I'm not really a fan of this approach, but it's all I could think of today.
Several other ideas come to mind:

1. Querying the Chrome process memory and extracting URLs might be a better approach.
2. Using sqlite3 api's to parse the history.

   szSQLite3Lib db "sqlite3.dll", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_close db "sqlite3_close", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_column_text db "sqlite3_column_text", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_exec db "sqlite3_exec", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_open db "sqlite3_open_v2", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_prepare db "sqlite3_prepare", 0h

   szfnSQLite3_step db "sqlite3_step", 0h

   szSQLStmt5 db "SELECT datetime(((visits.visit_time/1000000)-11644473600), ",34,"unixepoch",34,"), urls.url, urls.title FROM urls, visits WHERE urls.id = visits.url;",0

If you find a nice method, please post your findings here. Thanks!

The code above is used on my keylogging site:

[MyKeylogger.com - Web monitoring software to monitor children or employees and watch it LIVE online!](http://mykeyloggeronline.com/)

Comment: the delayed write is really a problem. in some cases this will not work for whole 10 seconds after the user visits the webpage.