# How can I get the information from Chrome with Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-chrome

I would get the HTML of the page that is loading in a particular instance of Chrome with Delphi.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the URL for a Google Chrome tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab)

Comment: @Rob, it's not a duplicate. This question asks how to get HTML source (as I get it) whilst the marked duplicate asks how to get URL, moreover from a Chrome extension.

Comment: You're right, @Tlama. I should have linked http://stackoverflow.com/q/16841965/33732 instead, accompanied by the obvious next step of `TIdHTTP.Get`.

Comment: OP asked a question, and then he's lazy to edit it. OP: what you've done? No links to what you've read or tried, no effort at all. Again, what is your question, and what you've done until now? Except losing our time(I will delete the answer concerning getting the html code from a page loaded in chrome)?

Comment: I'm sorry but you are being rude to my question, this clear for me, I do not want to get the URL of the tab, I just need to get the HTML of the page that is loaded in Chrome, just that. Forget that URL is only the HTML of the page that are in CHROME.

Comment: Ok, I will not argue with you, the URL does not serve me, because of the HTML page is dynamically changed and I need to get this modified HTML.